# Adding a number to a text file with a loop

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a day-and-month text file like this:

day=

```
8
9
10
15
1
```

month=

```
3
6
7
10
1
```

I need to add "0" to lines, including only one-digit numbers. I need to write a loop to find a one-digit number in all the lines and add "0" to the left of the number like;

day=

```
03
06
07
10
01
```

month=

```
03
06
07
10
01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` to pad the numbers with `0` accordingly:

```
while read num; do printf '%0.2d\n' "$num"; done <file.txt
```

To save the output in the same file:

```
while read num; do printf '%0.2d\n' "$num"; done <file.txt | tee file.txt
```

Comment: your second command print the data on the screen. How I can supress this print, I only want to save.

Comment: @deepblue_86 Use `while read num; do printf '%0.2d\n' "$num"; done <file.txt | tee file.txt >/dev/null`

Comment: You should [avoid while loop in shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906).

Comment: @cuonglm No, you don't need to avoid `while` in general. You do however need to understand that each command you invoke in a shell script takes some time, so many iterations of a while loop will take a long time. The `read` command has a number of caveats to pay attention to. Using it without understanding those caveats can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @kasperd: What you said are the reasons we should avoid using `while` loop in shell script. I invite you to read the link I gave in my comment for more details..

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks but I think as far as this example is concerned we are safe :)

Answer (score 5):

```
xargs printf "%.2d\n" <file.txt
```

Comment: I really like this solution. **1.** It uses `xargs` which is often being forgotten. **2.** It takes advantage of the possibility of `printf` to format multiple arguments using a single formatting expression. **3.** `printf` allows it to accept multiple input formats of numbers like for example hexadecimal `0x1a`.  **4.** `printf` tests the input to be a number and sensibly reports problems to `stderr`.

Comment: I noticed just one considerable disadvantage: multiple values on a single line will result in multiple lines on the output. Try: `echo 1 2 3 | xargs printf "%.2d\n"`. This can be somehow resolved using `-d\\n` otption to `xargs`.

Answer (score 4):

Perl one-liner approach, suitable as probably every shell have perl preinstalled:

```
perl -ne 'printf("%02d\n",$_)'<numbers.txt > numbers_out.txt
```

Comment: yay ! But because of the bad rep "enjoyed" by Perl these days, I personally always provide a kind of on-the-spot tutorial for at least options and regex syntax. Just a suggestion (+1 in any case).

Comment: Perl has a bad rep because there's a lot of java programmers who like 'java style' syntax, and they don't get the C style syntax of `perl`. This doesn't mean they're right. (All the anti-perl arguments apply to `sed`/`awk`, but they're still pretty popular. And you _can_ write nice code in perl).

Comment: @Cbhihe That's rather common mechanism (printf) available in many programming languages/unix, also redirecting streams/files is common Unix mechanism. 

About perl -ne:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212378/what-should-every-perl-hacker-know-about-perl-ne

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` - tool suited for tasks as batch or stream editing of text files or streams.

- as a filter to be used in a pipe:
  `sed 's/^[0-9]$/0&/'`
- as a command to edit a file:
  `sed -i 's/^[0-9]$/0&/' numfile.txt`

The code will prepend `0` to lines containing just a single digit `0` - `9`. Instead of `[0-9]` you can also use `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: -- a more general and thriftier solution than that offered by @heemayl, not to mention very much preferable to the while loop, imo. Kudos (+1)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` approach. Redirecting output back to file with creating `tmp.txt` and replacing original file with `tmp.txt` once the command is done.

Command

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]$/ {$1="0"$1}1'  numFile.txt  > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt numFile.txt
```

Sample output

```
xieerqi:$ cat numFile.txt                                                      
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

xieerqi:$ awk '/^[[:digit:]]$/ {$1="0"$1}1'  numFile.txt  > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt numFile.txt 

xieerqi:$ cat numFile.txt                                                      
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```